# How to create more than one column DataTemplate for ListView

Tags: xaml, listview, winrt-xaml

Below is the DataTemplate for GridView. I just change GridView to ListView

I want to do this:

2 or more columns in DataTemplate for the ListView to display

a) 2 columns Text

or

b) 2 columns Image in Square Box like 300 x 200.

How to I design the DataTemplate for ListView?

Thanks

1) DataTemplate declare in ResourceDictionary for Gridview. Can use this for ListView?

---

```XAML
<DataTemplate x:Key="CustomerTemplate">
    <Grid Background="Blue"  Width="300" Height="200">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           Margin="20,10,0,0" 
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           FontSize="24"
                           FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding No}" 
                           Grid.Row="1"
                           Margin="20,0,0,0" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="18"/>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Contact}" 
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           Margin="20,0,0,0" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="18"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" 
                           Grid.Row="3"
                           Margin="20,0,0,0" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           FontSize="18"/>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" 
                           Grid.Row="3"
                           Margin="200,0,0,0" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           FontSize="18"/>

    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

-- Use the DataTemplate for ListView. 
What need to do for the DataTemplate?

---

```XAML
<ListView x:Name="CustomersGridView" 
          Grid.Row="1"               
          Foreground="White"     
          SelectionMode="None"
          IsSwipeEnabled="True"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource CustomersViewSource}}" 
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomerTemplate}"
          ItemClick="CustomersGridView_ItemClick"      
          SelectionChanged="CustomersGridView_SelectionChanged">
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an outer grid and add 2 more columns to that.

```XAML
<Grid Width="900">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- FIRST COLUMN -->
    <Grid Background="Blue"  Width="300" Height="200" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Margin="20,10,0,0" 
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               VerticalAlignment="Top"
                               FontSize="24"
                               FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding No}" 
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Margin="20,0,0,0" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               FontSize="18"/>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Contact}" 
                               Grid.Row="2"
                               Margin="20,0,0,0" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               FontSize="18"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" 
                               Grid.Row="3"
                               Margin="20,0,0,0" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Top"
                               FontSize="18"/>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" 
                               Grid.Row="3"
                               Margin="200,0,0,0" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Top"
                               FontSize="18"/>

    </Grid>

    <!-- SECOND COLUMN -->
    <Grid Grid.Column="1"></Grid>

    <!-- THIRD COLUMN -->
    <Grid Grid.Column="2"></Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Can the 1st Column content be the same as in column 2 and 3? I want all 3 columns display customer info. Like I have 10 customers from database, I want to display row 1 with 3 customers, then row 2 another 3 customer and so on. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, it's doable.  But thinking it over, isn't that what a GridView is?

Comment: Yes, I need vertical scrolling and GridView is lagging when touch to scroll vertical. ListView is for good for vertical scrolling. Can you help me on the DataTemplate for Image so I can test it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a GridView with some adjustments to the internal ScrollViewer of the GridView? like making it vertically scrollable and allowing it to have 3 items per row. By doing so, you can just keep the data template to hold just single item. Here is the sample for that:

```
<GridView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">

    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="3" Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```